# Разделить переменную на несколько

Tags: php, переменные

Здрасте! Есть записть в базе типа "Коля,Алеша,Валя,Оля". Нужно эту переменную разбивать на все запятые по одной, а именно должен быть такой вид:

```
$row = Коля;
$row1 = Алеша;
$row2 = Валя;
$row3 = Оля;
```

Заранее боагадарен :)

Comment: Вы язык не указали

Comment: забыл :(   это на пхп

Comment: `explode()` только он массив выдаст, что в данном случае явно лучше, в случае чего в переменные перенесете.

Comment: $row = $row['пер_которую_делить'];
$last = substr($row, -1);
if ($last == ','){
$gallery = substr($row, 0, strlen($row)-1); }
$imena = explode(",", $row);
   foreach ( $imena as $file);

<?=imena?>

i+++

Вот так работает но мне это не подходит так как выводит одной переменной (это я с галереи стащил, там так фотки записываются в поле text через запятую )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list($row, $row1, $row2, $row3) = explode(',', 'Коля,Алеша,Валя,Оля');
```

или если имен больше

```
$row = explode(',', 'Коля,Алеша,Валя,Оля');
$row[0]; // Коля
$row[1]; // Алеша
$row[2]; // Валя
$row[3]; // Оля
//$row[n]...
```

- **[explode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php)** — Разбивает строку с помощью разделителя
- **[list](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.list.php)** — Присваивает переменным из списка значения подобно массиву

Answer (score 1):

`explode` — *Разбивает строку с помощью разделителя*
Пример использования:

```
$pizza  = "кусок1 кусок2 кусок3 кусок4 кусок5 кусок6";
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
echo $pieces[0]; // кусок1
echo $pieces[1]; // кусок2
```

Почитать о [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php)

---

*В Вашем случае*

```
$database  = "Коля,Алеша,Валя,Оля";
$names = explode(",", $database);
echo $names[0]; // Коля
echo $names[1]; // Алеша
echo $names[2]; // Валя
echo $names[3]; // Оля
```

*Надеюсь помог!*

Answer (score 1):

`array explode(string $delimiter, string $string)`

Возвращает массив строк, полученных разбиением строки `string` с использованием `delimiter` в качестве разделителя

```
$mainRow= "Коля,Алеша,Валя,Оля";
$rowPieces = explode(",", $mainRow);
$row = $rowPieces[0]; // Коля
$row1 = $rowPieces[1]; // Алеша
$row2 = $rowPieces[2]; // Валя
$row3 = $rowPieces[3]; // Оля
```

Comment: @Vladislav_Carley если вам ответ помог - отметьте его как правильный.